# How to maintain repetitive block of Asserts in TestNG Tests

Tags: selenium, testng, regression, ui-automation

*I have an application which has numerous automated test cases in regression written in Selenium and using TestNG.  Each of the test is validation a different workflow and in the end validates a page which is an product of the workflow executed.  Usually, this page is always same and has numerous asserts (around 20+).  Most of these asserts are repetitive, since they are checking the same values on the page after the workflow is executed ex:*

```
**Test1** 
{
Execute workflow 1

ASSERT BLOCK {
20+ ASSERTS
}

**Test2**
 {
Execute workflow 2

ASSERT BLOCK {
20+ ASSERTS
}

}
```

This Assert block is same for all the test cases, so in the future if an assert needs to be added or removed, it has to be done on each of the Test.  This is somewhat of an overhead to maintenance.  Can someone suggest what would be the best way to handle this situation, in order to enhance maintainability and remove redundancy in the tests due to asserts.

Comment: Would adding the asserts in the `@AfterMethod` will help, as `@AfterMethod` will be executed after each of your test method and perform the asserts.

Comment: Yes I did trying adding all these asserts to @AfterMethod in the base test, but when an assert fails, it shows Configuration Failure and not Test Failure, so not sure if its the right thing to do

Comment: You can handle in using the `listener` and force the test to fail on the SA failure as part of  your `listener` implementation.

Comment: I am trying to find out what is the best practice in such a case, I mean there might be tests which require repetitive asserts, so what should be the best practice to manage this

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out if all those Asserts makes sense to be executed after each workflow.
If yes, what I would do is to keep all the elements that are being checked into a single array or enum depending on your elements types, where I can easy add or remove them. Then on the test itself I will just loop through the assertions.

This way is much easier to maintain as you maintain only in a single place what goes in and out and also you avoid duplicate code.

Comment: Is looping through in the test the correct thing to do as per best practice? Also, can you share some piece of code to clarify this.

Answer (score -1):

what about creating a common method keeping all the 20 + assertions into it

Comment: Common method can be created in BaseTest, but then how do you use SoftAsserts with it, while keeping the common method in one place?